# Adding a foreign key constraint with a Laravel Migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

I have started a new Laravel 5.5 project and I am receiving the following error when trying to add a foreign key to my `users` table:

> General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_organization_id_foreign` foreign key (`organization_id`) references `organizations` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Here is the migration code for the `organization` table:

```
Schema::create('organizations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('subdomain')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

Here is the migration code for the `users` table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('organization_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

I have researched this error online and the common thing to make sure of are that the data types are the same. From what I can see, they are the same. What's even crazier is that if I run this query in the database directly it works:

```
alter table `users` add constraint `users_organization_id_foreign` foreign key (`organization_id`) references `organizations` (`id`)
```

Comment: Have you added dbal to  your composer.json?if not add,  composer require doctrine/dbal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, in each Laravel fresh installation `users` table is created first. But since you're adding a constraint in this table, you need to create `organizations` table first.

So, put `organizations` table migration before `users` table migration by changing `organizations` migration date in the file name:

```
2014_01_01_000000_create_organizations_table.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Going along with Alexey's answer. I would also suggest that you enable/disable foreign key constraints before you run your migrations:

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
// Your migration code.
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

This way you don't need to rename your migration files.